# Is a struct with the format 1.0.0 possible?

Tags: c#, struct, interface, module, version

So I'm playing around a bit with the possibilities of modules for an application I'm building and I'd like to version them.

These modules which are dlls implement an interface with a property for the version of this module. The format should be "Major.Minor.Build".

If I create a property of type String, the possibility of a version like "Major.Minor" or "Major.Minor.Build.Revision" exists. I want to prevent that.

So I had the idea of a struct like Double but with a third digit. My question is now, is this even possible and if yes, how can I implement something like this?

In the class it should look like this:

```cs
public class MyModuleContext : IModuleContext
{
    public ModuleVersion Version { get; set; } = 1.0.0;
    // more interface things ...
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: take a look at System.Version class and do the same with 3 build components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `class` that meets your needs:

```
public class Version: IVersion
{
    public int Major { get; }
    public int Minor { get; }
    public int Build { get; }

    public override string ToString =>
        $”{Major}.{Minor}.{Build}” 

    public Version(int major, int minor, int build)
    {
        //omitted argument validation
        Major = major;
        Minor = minor;
        Build = build;
    }
}
```

If you are mainly going to be passing `IVersion` references around, you are better off implementing this as a reference type or you’ll be boxing the value type all over the place.

It’s up to you if you want to implement value equality semantics, comparison logic, etc. It’s all pretty trivial.